# Should "is" be used here?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

The point is that money does not change hands as randomly as (IS) suggested by the aforementioned kind of statements.

Comment: Yes. The singular verb is governed by the singular fact of "money not changing hands as randomly as..."

Answer (score 1):

It's optional.

Parallel constructions are

> Here is the story, as told to me by my aunt
>
> I remember *The Pirates of Penzance*, as performed by the D'Oyly Carte Company.

In each case a copula (here 'was') may be inserted before 'as', but it seems more natural to me without.

Comment: Thank you very much. I cannot upvote your answer, because it was not possible, as I am new here and do not have 15 points of reputation.

Comment: Colin, do you mean _after_ "as"?

Comment: These aren’t entirely parallel constructions—the one in the question is an “as X as Y” construction, not an “as [=in the manner]” construction.

Answer (score -1):

Doesn't need and you can use either because if it is passive form it is mandatory to use "to be" after "as". but in general speaking you can skip it too.

Comment: This **is** a passive construction. There is no such grammatical rule that a copula is mandatory after _as_ in passive constructions.